# Passing object to a function and accessing its properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, jquery-plugins, prototype

I am new to prototype model coding in JavaScript.

I am trying to access properties(`$owl_nav` and `$owl_dots`) of an object(`elements`) by passing the object to a function(`setOverflowWrapperHeight`), in code

```
function setOverflowWrapperHeight(elem) {
  var owl_dots_height =  elem.$owl_dots.height();
  var owl_nav_height = elem.$owl_nav.height();
  $('.overflow-wrapper').height(owl_dots_height + owl_nav_height + 150);
}

function NextQ(elements) {
  this.checked_input = elements.checked_input;
  this.$owl_ques_carousel = elements.$owl_ques_carousel;
  this.$owl_nav = elements.$owl_nav;
  this.$owl_dots = elements.$owl_dots;
  this.init();
}
NextQ.prototype.init = function () {
  this.bindEvents();
};

NextQ.prototype.bindEvents = function () {
  var _this = this;
  this.$owl_ques_carousel.on('click', '.nutrition_assessment_next_quest', function (event) {
  _this.$owl_ques_carousel.on('translated.owl.carousel', function (event) {
  setOverflowWrapperHeight(elements);
  });
});

$(function () {
  var $user_meta_div = $('div.user_meta_data_div');
  setOverflowWrapperHeight($user_meta_div);

  /***** NextQ Object *****/
  elements = {
    $owl_ques_carousel: $('.owl-carousel#ques-carousel'),
    checked_input: true,
    $owl_nav: $('.owl-nav'),
    $owl_dots: $('.owl-dots')
  };

  /***** Create instance of NextQ Function *****/
  nextQ = new NextQ(elements);
});
```

But the console outputs this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined
```

I want to know if this is even legal. If yes, where am I going wrong?

Comment: Type debugger; on the first line of your function and hard refresh the browser page. your code should now beak in the function (if you have your developer tools open) and then you can view what your object looks like.

Comment: You are calling setOverflowWrapperHeight($user_meta_div); before you setup elements object. You just pass an DOM node nto it first, so it doesn't contains any properties which you are reffering inside function.

Comment: @Andrew Tried your solution, Dev tool now gives very different result for function setOverflowWrapperHeight() argument elem than it gave earlier when I set breakpoints in dev tool and enter the function setOverflowWrapperHeight() by stepping into it. That time elem argument had the correct elemenrs object

Comment: @Andrew   With debugger it contains $('div.user_meta_data_div')

Comment: Have you changed anything in the html. The j query selector is potentially not find the element div.user_meta_data_div. Maybe change the selector to search for the class name only $('. user_meta_data_div')